# How to prevent @media query from triggering css animations?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, css-animations, styled-components

I'm currently working on my portfolio website and I encountered a problem.

I have an animation that I want to only be triggered on certain screen size. So I put it inside a @media query. It works as it should but there is one problem. Every time the screen crosses that breakpoint this animation is re-triggered automatically. I just want it to be triggered initially when the page loads.

If anyone can help, I would highly appreciate it. I am using Next.js for the project.

Thanks in advance!

Styled Component code:

```js
const TypeWriter = styled.h1`
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 5.4rem;
    margin-top: 20rem;
    max-width: 100%;

    @keyframes typewriter {
        to {
            left: 100%;
        }
    }

    @keyframes blink {
        to {
            background: transparent;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: 935px) {
        &::before,
        &::after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        &::before {
            background: #e9ecef;
            animation: typewriter 3s 1s steps(39) forwards;
        }
        &::after {
            background-color: #f9c9d7;
            animation: typewriter 3s 1s steps(39) forwards,
                blink 0.7s steps(39) infinite;
            width: 0.1em;
        }
    }
`;
```

Comment: Yes we will certainly help but with some code `html` `CSS` from your side, will certainly help us too.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried as a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: Hello @Rana, thanks for you reply, I added the markup code.